# Magento 1.9 Cron job

Tags: magento-1.9

I am using cron job in magento which runs for every 2 minutes. And I have set the ubuntu cron job to run magento's cron.sh for evey 5 minutes. The cron job of magento is initiating fine, it can be track down in the `cron_schedule` table which is in `pending status`.

The problem is, the cron job is not running either its not changing the status.

After some time it is going to the `missing status` http://prntscr.com/7o4zwv  with the following message

```
exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Too late for the schedule.' in /var/www/html/sports/app/Mage.php:595
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/sports/app/code/core/Mage/Cron/Model/Observer.php(293): Mage::throwException('Too late for th...')
#1 /var/www/html/sports/app/code/core/Mage/Cron/Model/Observer.php(72): Mage_Cron_Model_Observer->_processJob(Object(Mage_Cron_Model_Schedule), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element))
#2 /var/www/html/sports/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1338): Mage_Cron_Model_Observer->dispatch(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#3 /var/www/html/sports/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1317): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Mage_Cron_Model_Observer), 'dispatch', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#4 /var/www/html/sports/app/Mage.php(448): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('default', Array)
#5 /var/www/html/sports/cron.php(76): Mage::dispatchEvent('default')
#6 {main}
```

Is there anything am i missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am using cron job in magento which runs for every 2 minutes. And I have set the ubuntu cron job to run magento's cron.sh for evey 5 minutes

That's your issue.

Change the system cron to be executed at least as frequently as the most frequent task (ie. every 2 minutes in this case).

---

It is important to check that you don't have any task overlap (ie. one task taking so long it prevents others from running).

[Aoe Scheduler](https://github.com/AOEpeople/Aoe_Scheduler) is excellent for visualising this and it also supports blacklist/whitelisting tasks (if you do have one that runs for too long blocking other tasks).

Comment: Hi, i tried by making magento cron to run for every 5 minutes, also the ubuntu cron for every 5 minutes.. But still its not working, Is there any other way to solve it??

Comment: Yes, change the cron frequency to every two minutes as I suggested.